# How can I auto fix tslint errors in vuejs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, tslint

I am running `vue-cli-service lint --fix` on my vuejs/typescript project. Like expected most of the linting errors/warning gets fixed automatically.

But there is specific tslint rule(`"semicolon": [true, "always", "ignore-interfaces"]`) I want to auto fix with this command. Say my typescript interface looks like this(expected lint result).

```
interface component {
    type: "input" | "dropdown" | "checkbox",
    hidden?: boolean
}
```

After running lint it formats it like this. Message is `[eslint] Replace`,`with`;`(prettier/prettier)`

```
interface component {
    type: "input" | "dropdown" | "checkbox";
    hidden?: boolean;
}
```

I have added this rule `"semicolon": [true, "always", "ignore-interfaces"]` to the tslint file, but it doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console message (`[eslint] Replace , with ; (prettier/prettier)`) suggests you had selected the `ESLint + Prettier` option when generating your project with Vue CLI; but ESLint doesn't support `tslint.json` out of the box (a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-tslint) is needed, but YMMV).

An alternative is to switch to TSLint, and edit the generated `tslint.json` to include your desired `semicolon` rule.

Comment: I tried that plugin but it doesn't seem to go well with the `templates` in the `.vue` files. Also fount this. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/761. Thanks for your response.

Comment: This seems to be a [known Prettier quirk](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1944). Is it not feasible to regenerate the project and select the `TSLint` linter option?

Comment: I can but for the current moment it is trivial to do that. I will play a with https://github.com/alexjoverm/tslint-config-prettier . But looking at the issues for vue-cli it looks like it is in the works getting tslint-prettier part of the vue create.